# Artifactory docker registry login failed with 400 bad request

Tags: docker, authentication, artifactory

I am trying to login to the docker registry in artifactory. I was able to do it from curl but getting 400 bad request from docker login command. This is an enterprise artifactory so I do not have admin access for checking logs.

CURL

```
$ curl -I https://<EMAIL>:<TOKEN>@artifactory.myorg.com/api/docker/sample-docker/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 18:41:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: X-Oracle-BMC-LBS-Route=7f4f0554bc358efb45fcb4fede9cb5632a7b7b07; Path=/
X-Artifactory-Id: 524cb1f38361d95717ff9ba8b8d5fc805d4547e6
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: node2
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
```

Docker login command

```
$ docker login artifactory.myorg.com
Username: <EMAIL>
Password:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://artifactory.myorg.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request
```

Docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:21:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 11):

this depends what is the setup on Artifactory side.
There are 3 methods how to setup access to Docker repositories:

- Repository Path (Direct Access)
- Port
- Sub-domain (mostly used as JFrog recommends this one)

You need to ask the Artifactory support team or find in their documentation which method is used. `docker login` is different based on the method used. Unfortunately, what I can tell, the 'Set Me Up' button for Docker repositories always shows commands for `Repository Path` method and does not reflect the actual method configured.

For `Sub-domain` the login and pull/push should look like this:
`docker login <REPOSITORY_KEY>.artifactory.myorg.com`
`docker pull / push <REPOSITORY_KEY>.artifactory.myorg.com/<IMAGE>:<TAG>`
so in your example:
`docker login sample-docker.artifactory.myorg.com`

For `Repository Path` the login and pull/push should look like this:
`docker login artifactory.myorg.com`
`docker pull / push artifactory.myorg.com/<REPOSITORY_KEY>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>`

For `Port` the login and pull/push should look like this:
`docker login artifactory.myorg.com:<REPOSITORY_PORT>`
`docker pull / push artifactory.myorg.com:<REPOSITORY_PORT>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>`

Note:
You will also get `400 Bad Request` if you try to use non-existing repository.